# Find the domain and range of $f(x)=\log_3(5+4x-x^2)$

Tags: functions, inequality, quadratics

Solve $f(x)=\log_3(5+4x-x^2)$

Finding the domain:

$$5+4x-x^2>0$$
$$x^2-4x-5<0$$
$$x^2-5x+x-5<0$$
$$(x-5)(x+1)<0$$
$$x\in (-1,5)$$

**For finding the range, I used two methods but both are giving different results.**

I$^{st}$ method: Just placing the range in the function

$$f(x)=\log_3(5-(x^2+4-4x-4))$$
$$f(x)=\log_3(5-(x-2)^2+4)$$
$$f(x)=\log_3(9-(x-2)^2)$$
$$f(x)=\log_3(9-((-1,5)-2)^2)$$
$$f(x)=\log_3(9-(-3,3)^2)$$
$$f(x)=\log_3(9-(0,9))$$
$$f(x)=\log_3(0,9)$$
$$f(x)=(-\infty,2)$$

II$^{nd}$ method: Using the formula of range of downward parabola $\left(-\infty,\dfrac{-D}{4a}\right]$

$$f(x)=\log_3((-\infty,9])$$
$$f(x)=\log_3((0,9])$$
$$f(x)=(-\infty,2]$$

Why is it so? Why I am getting different results for different methods. Please help me in this.

Comment: The domain is limited by the solutions: $5+4x-x^2=(1+x)(5-x)$ giving $x\in(-1,5)$ for the quadratic to be positive.  The "downward parabola" method is not very clear on why it would be used and what its conditions are...

Comment: bro, it should be $5+4x-x^2$ should be greater than $0$ as for $0$, $\log$ is not defined.

Comment: Yes, corrected...

Comment: its a very powerful method, just try to get the maximum value of the downward parabola, you will get as $\dfrac{-D}{4a}$

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the same result.

For the first function, you should have a closed bracket on the right, since $f(2)$ is indeed $2$.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you, can you point out the mistake

Comment: the range of the parabola is (-infinity, 9] not (-infinity, 9)

Comment: so the range of f(x) is (-infinity, 2] not (-infinity, 2)

Comment: but you can see in the first method, I am getting $(-\infty,2)$

Comment: what is wrong in the first method?

Comment: you didn't include 2 in the range for the first method. a parabola includes its vertex in the range

Comment: see I am asking you a very simple question, in which step of the first method I did wrong

Comment: line 6 is incorrect. it should be [0,9)

Comment: ok, thanks, so stupid of me

Comment: because 0 is between (-3, 3) so when you square it 0 is included